# finding range of ascii characters

Tags: python

Is there a way to use a range of ascii characters without importing anything? I've tried

```
chr(range(32,127)) and range(chr(32,127))
```

but these had error messages

Comment: In this case, the problem was obvious. However, it is recommended that you post the error messages. They are very useful in complex cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call `chr` on each number in the range, not on the range itself:

```
map(chr, range(32, 127))
```

or

```
[chr(n) for n in range(32, 127)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do with them, you will need to do something similar to:

prints out the charactor without storing it:

```
for i in range(32,127):
    print (chr(i))
```

Stores the charactors in a list:

```
ascii = [chr(i) for i in range(32,127)]
```

The reason you were getting errors in your implementation is because in the first case you were trying to parse the range function into a charactor, and in the second one, the `chr` function does not take 2 arguments, and the `range` function does not take a char as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

maybe `map(chr, range(32, 127))` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
bytearray(range(32, 127)).decode()
```